# Создание анимации рамки вокруг input

Tags: html, css

Привет  всем, примерно месяц назад я задался вопросом: Как сделать анимацию рамки элемента в которого установлен `border-radius`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно мое решение не совсем правильно, но хочется поделится им с вами и услышать критику/советы по реализации даного функционала.

Для реализации данной фичи я решил использовать 2 блока одинаковых по размеру и 1 инпут который размещается над 2 блоками и немного меньше их (чтобы показать рамку).

```css
.outblock {
  position: relative;
}

.defaultBorder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.focusBorder {
  width: 1px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 75px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
 
.inputBlock {
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left:2px;
  width: 146px;
  height: 146px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 13px;
}

.inputBlock:focus ~ #outblock2 {
  width: 150px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='outblock'>
  <input type="text" class="inputBlock" placeholder="hello world">
  <div class="defaultBorder" id="outblock1"></div>
  <div class="focusBorder" id="outblock2"></div>
</div>
```